# I will show them the 'job of Bronx'

Tags: american-english, slang, north-american-english

Rocco Commisso is the Italian-American owner of the New York Cosmos and Fiorentina FC.

Italian journalists made fun of his funny Italian accent, and he responded saying this:

> I know that lots of Italians speak better than me, but when (journalists) confront me they should talk English and I'll show them the *job of Bronx*

What does he mean when he says *job of Bronx*? The Italian media is acting as if Commisso just threatened someone.

This is the [video](https://youtu.be/Bfhsdrfayds)

Comment: He may be referring to a [Bronx cheer](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bronx+cheer), but without more context (or confirmation from other sources) it's impossible to say. I for one have never heard "job of Bronx" used at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a one-off remark, non-standard. Not even totally non-Italian.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question from several days ago.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the guy invented this term or just meant to say something else..and I don't think he was referring to the Bronx cheer

Comment: Bronx cheer has nothing to do with what he said. Note that he was talking to the Italian Press.

Comment: He is from the Bronx and I think he is really saying: *And we'll show them how we do a job in the Bronx*. I can't quite catch what he says in Italian between the word job and the word Bronx but it is **not** the word **of**. The Bronx is known for being "tough guy territory" (not only mafia). He is railing against Sky TV which is US owned. Now, that's funny because his own company is owned by him, an American. In other words, we in the Bronx know how to do our job unlike these stupid TV reports from Sky. That is the idea here.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is just a personal expression as suggested in the following article  from the Italian newspaper [“Corriere della Sera](https://www.corriere.it/sport/20_febbraio_08/commisso-fazz-a-job-d-o-bronx-cosa-ha-detto-presidente-fiorentina-5dd5714a-4aa3-11ea-b474-2022aed4301a.shtml)”. Note that the real words are *“Fazz ‘a job d’o Bronx”* a mix of a southern italian dialect and English.

The sense of his (Commisso) words probably is:

> You make fun of me because I don’t speak Italian very well, but if you want to discuss with me in English, I’ll show you who is a  (genuine American) from Bronx.

The expression  may have sound threatening because of the common association people make (at least in Italy) of The Bronx with a violent and ruthless place.

Comment: Well, it's not about Bronx prejudices but how he said the thing.He basically told journalists that 'he will show them something' with a defiant attitude

Comment: @Zafalija - actually the key word is Bronx and what it evokes   In people’s mind.

Comment: To “ do the job” is also a typical mafia way to refer to committing  a crime.  He was not serious but the result was ...queer

Comment: That’s why the Press was ...impressed.

Comment: the word genuine and American are not there. "We'll show them how we do a job in the Bronx", where he is from. The Bronx is synonymous at times with "having tough guys".

Comment: @Lambie - yes I put them in brackets. That’s what he means.

Comment: It does not matter. He is not saying what you say he is saying. No need to apologize.

Answer (score -2):

He was actually translating "the Bronx job" (which to Italian back to English will translate as "the job of Bronx"), which is a euphemism for a mafia hit (killing).